Why is my object filled with incorrect values?
I'm querying a third party API (ESPN Fantasy) from my front end to clean the data and use it in my app. While adding new data details, I have an issue : when trying to apply detailed raters to my players, I end up getting wrong values. So I logged the data during the process and I get this weird result :

The first object is the raw data from the third party API, with the correct values. The second object is what I get when I parse them. As you can see, the collapsed version of my object has the correct values but the expanded version has wrong values. Those wrong values are the one I end up with in my app.
Here is the code where I parse the data for each player :
const basePlayerRaters: PlayerCategoriesRaters = {
  [StatsCategories.FG]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.FT]: 0,
  [StatsCategories["3PM"]]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.REB]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.AST]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.STL]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.BLK]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.TO]: 0,
  [StatsCategories.PTS]: 0,
};

const buildPlayerRaters = (
  rawRater: PlayerRatings | undefined
): PlayerCategoriesRaters => {
  const output = basePlayerRaters;
  if (rawRater) {
    rawRater.statRankings.forEach((value) => {
      const key = RaterCategories.get(value.forStat);
      if (key) {
        output[key] = value.rating;
      }
    });
  }
  console.log("build raters 2 : ", rawRater, output);

  return output;
};

While I've seen that console.log and object are not a good match because of async references, I don't understand where these wrong values come from and why I get them and.

"I don't understand where these wrong values come from" - some other code is mutating the object after you've logged it (and apparently, after you've returned in from buildPlayerRatings)

@Bergi : I call this function once for every player but the object is inside the scope of this function. It's weird.

Objects don't have a "scope". The return doesn't create a copy of the data, it returns a reference to the mutable object

If you need further help with this, you'll need to post a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem; it'll include the call as well as what is happening to the returned object later.

Replacing the return output; in my code by return {...output}; made the trick for some reason.

No. That makes your code no longer mutate the object you logged, but your code is still mutating the object you returned. If you didn't intend that, find that code and fix it before it causes more grave bugs than unexpected logs.
